# JPA exception: Object: null is not a known entity type

Tags: java, exception, jpa, persist

Hi I'm new in JPA and when I want to persist object I get these errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:437)
    at database.TarpineManager.persist(TarpineManager.java:31)
    at gijos.InsertToDB.insertLink(InsertToDB.java:34)
    at gijos.VilpraParser.run(VilpraParser.java:77)
```

There is my firs object class, which I want to do relation with other XLinksMedia class, I think problem is in

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "xParserLink", targetEntity = XLinksMedia.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<XLinksMedia> fotos;
```

but I do not know what is wrong:

```
package database.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "x_parser_links")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findAll", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByLinkId", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.linkId = :linkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByPageId", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.pageId = :pageId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByLink", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.link = :link"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByLevel", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.level = :level"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByLinkType", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.linkType = :linkType"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByCreateDate", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.createDate = :createDate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XParserLinks.findByDelDate", query = "SELECT x FROM XParserLinks x WHERE x.delDate = :delDate")})
public class XParserLinks implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "link_id")
    private Integer linkId;
    @Column(name = "page_id")
    private Integer pageId;
    @Column(name = "link")
    private String link;
    @Column(name = "level")
    private Integer level;
    @Column(name = "link_type")
    private Short linkType;
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createDate;
    @Column(name = "del_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date delDate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "tev_link_id")
    @OneToOne
    private XParserLinks tevas;   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xParserLink", targetEntity = XLinksMedia.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<XLinksMedia> fotos;


    public XParserLinks() {
    }

    public XParserLinks(Integer linkId) {
        this.linkId = linkId;
    }

    public Integer getLinkId() {
        return linkId;
    }

    public void setLinkId(Integer linkId) {
        this.linkId = linkId;
    }

    public Integer getPageId() {
        return pageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(Integer pageId) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Integer getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(Integer level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Short getLinkType() {
        return linkType;
    }

    public void setLinkType(Short linkType) {
        this.linkType = linkType;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Date getDelDate() {
        return delDate;
    }

    public void setDelDate(Date delDate) {
        this.delDate = delDate;
    }

    public XParserLinks getTevas() {
        return tevas;
    }

    public void setTevas(XParserLinks tevas) {
        this.tevas = tevas;
    }

    public List<XLinksMedia> getFotos() {
        return fotos;
    }

    public void setFotos(List<XLinksMedia> fotos) {
        this.fotos = fotos;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (linkId != null ? linkId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof XParserLinks)) {
            return false;
        }
        XParserLinks other = (XParserLinks) object;
        if ((this.linkId == null && other.linkId != null) || (this.linkId != null && !this.linkId.equals(other.linkId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "database.entity.XParserLinks[ linkId=" + linkId + " ]";
    }

}
```

Second class for *fotos* object

```
package database.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "x_links_media")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "XLinksMedia.findAll", query = "SELECT x FROM XLinksMedia x"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XLinksMedia.findByLinkId", query = "SELECT x FROM XLinksMedia x WHERE x.xLinksMediaPK.linkId = :linkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "XLinksMedia.findByImage", query = "SELECT x FROM XLinksMedia x WHERE x.xLinksMediaPK.image = :image")})
public class XLinksMedia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected XLinksMediaPK xLinksMediaPK;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "link_id")
    private XParserLinks xParserLink;

    public XLinksMedia() {
    }

    public XLinksMedia(XLinksMediaPK xLinksMediaPK) {
        this.xLinksMediaPK = xLinksMediaPK;
    }

    public XLinksMedia(int linkId, String image) {
        this.xLinksMediaPK = new XLinksMediaPK(linkId, image);
    }

    public XLinksMediaPK getXLinksMediaPK() {
        return xLinksMediaPK;
    }

    public void setXLinksMediaPK(XLinksMediaPK xLinksMediaPK) {
        this.xLinksMediaPK = xLinksMediaPK;
    }

    public XParserLinks getxParserLink() {
        return xParserLink;
    }

    public void setxParserLink(XParserLinks xParserLink) {
        this.xParserLink = xParserLink;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (xLinksMediaPK != null ? xLinksMediaPK.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof XLinksMedia)) {
            return false;
        }
        XLinksMedia other = (XLinksMedia) object;
        if ((this.xLinksMediaPK == null && other.xLinksMediaPK != null) || (this.xLinksMediaPK != null && !this.xLinksMediaPK.equals(other.xLinksMediaPK))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "database.entity.XLinksMedia[ xLinksMediaPK=" + xLinksMediaPK + " ]";
    }

}
```

And to persist object is this method:

```
    obj= new XParserLinks();
    obj.setCreateDate(new Date());
    obj.setLevel(1);
    obj.setPageId(2);
    obj.setLink(link);
    obj.setLinkType((short) 2);

        TarpineManager.startTransaction();

        TarpineManager.persist(obj);

        System.out.println("NAUJAS LINKAS");
        TarpineManager.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: If you think that `OneToMany` is the problem, try commenting that out and running it. If it works, then you know it is the problem, if you get the same issue you know to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess: `fotos` instance variable of the entity you're trying to persist named `obj` is never set and therefore `null`. Null pointers do not seem to be a legal entity for one-to-many relations.